# Why is there no way to link JS files together without using a bundler?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I've been working on this problem for a couple days now-ish. I am trying to modularize my JS project. I have a JS file that I'm trying to modularize without using things like webpack or needing to run a server to see the results. However I don't want to disable CORS in my browser, because this sets false precedence for me that it will work on my GitHub Pages repo.

The result needs to work on GitHub Pages as well since I would be copying this code setup directly into my GitHub Pages project.

I've been grappling with Webpack for the greater part of 32 hours and it's not been going anywhere.

[Link to Project](https://codepen.io/Setari/pen/LYXqozv)
`Please see the codepen link, couldn't get code blocks to work in the editor here`

I am aware 99% of the code is not "modular-ready" as I found out last night, I am just trying to get the pikmin object at the top to export into the main.js file and be rendered on the page and learn how to do this, for now.

A developer friend recommended to use the globalObject and update that but I would prefer not to do that as this is a portfolio project and I don't want to use bad practices like that. It does work, but... eh. It worked with the pikmin object, which is why I'm just starting with this small bit of code, for now.

IMO I think it would be nice if we could just modularize our code (as beginners) by just separating the code out into files and using import/export within vanilla JS instead of having to require all these extra tools, but maybe that's just me.

I've been doing a ton of googling on the issue and it either points to using a packer (Webpack, etc) or running the code on a live server, or both. I've tried setting up Webpack to no avail multiple times. I can't find any guidance resources on how to use Webpack to set up an existing project, and also it is unclear if Webpack automatically sets up it's own auto-packer or if I need to use the other Webpack thing that adds additional modules as I create them.

My goal is to take every block of code out and move it into its own separate file for further development purposes and bug-finding, or at least as much code as I possibly can.

Comment: There is a way. It's called [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: *couldn't get code blocks to work in the editor here* — huh? it's insanely easy, there's literally a button that does it for you.

Comment: Also: *separating the code out into files and using import/export within vanilla JS* — yes that is correct; what exactly is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: Bundlers aren't a requirement for vanilla JavaScript, which can run and be modularized by itself on browser and node.js environments. But bundlers may be required for the libraries/frameworks you choose to use. Knowing that distinction may help you with what you're aiming to do and in choosing the tools you want to use.

Comment: Mozilla Developer Web Docs are the place to start your journey https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: @Pointy - Whenever I try to import items into my main script.js file, it throws a couple console errors: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
pikminTotal.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
So, fine. I change the HTML tag for the script.js and pikminTotal.js to modules (type = "module"). I've tried just setting script.js, and pikminTotal.js individually and both. If I set it on script.js, I get the CORS error that requires it to be run on a server to run export code into the script.js file. Same thing basically for pikminTotal.js basically

Comment: I am also not using any frameworks/libraries besides google font API which I shouldn't think would cause any issues in this case, so I'm not messing about with removing those.

Crazy that all of my googling about modularization and stuff never brought up the MDN docs. I'll read through those.

Comment: Even the MDN states: You need to pay attention to local testing — if you try to load the HTML file locally (i.e. with a file:// URL), you'll run into CORS errors due to JavaScript module security requirements. You need to do your testing through a server.

This is the reason for my question, why does trying to perform modularization on js files require a server environment? This leads down a rabbit hole of requiring webpack-esque npms to bundle code together as well. 

There's no way to do this without using a local server?

Comment: Many of the modern Web APIs require your code to be served on a page from a webserver, mostly for security reasons (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, Same-Origin Policy, etc.), hence the reason why `file://` won't work. Webpack is not required for you to have a development server. What you're looking for is a simple "static server" to host the HTML that loads your script. If you already have Node.js installed, use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to serve your files. Run `npx http-server path/containing/your/html` to serve a directory with your HTML.

Comment: Yeah my goal was to do it through local files, but I guess I'll have to do a static server. Thanks all.